# Package listings: Error "Undefined control sequence." because of single-quote-symbol?

Tags: symbols, errors, listings, highlighting

I'm using the package `listings` and came across a problem displaying an SQL statement within an java environment. This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\lstset{
 backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
 tabsize=4,
 rulecolor=,
 language=matlab,
 basicstyle=\scriptsize,
 upquote=true,
 aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
 columns=fixed,
 showstringspaces=false,
 extendedchars=true,
 breaklines=true,
 prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
 frame=single,
 showtabs=false,
 showspaces=false,
 showstringspaces=false,
 identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
 commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
 stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java]
  Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:rel.db", "user", "pass");
  Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
  stmt.execupdate("INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN VALUES ('C1R1R2R3R4R5R6', 1234, 1170, 1189, 1934)");
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The problem is in the 4th line as the SQL statement is using single quotes within a string. I get the latex error (from log):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lst@um'@ ->\lst@ifupquote \textquotesingle 
                                        \else \char 39\relax \fi 
l.299 ...cupdate("INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN VALUES ('C
                                              1R1R2R3R4R5R6', 1234, 117...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

How to fix this? Is this a bug - I don't get what's wrong with using single quotes within double quotes?

**Update**: Solution seems to be adding `\usepackage{textcomp}` *before* modifying the listings styles.

Comment: Your excerpt works fine for me. What version of the _listings_ package do you use? Could you provide a complete code example that shows the issue?

Comment: Did you say `\usepackage{textcomp}`? You probably have some customizations that require this package.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comments, i was just about to create a minimal working example while noticing that i need to add the package `textcomp` _before_ modifying the listings styles. i will update the question in a minute.

Comment: You also need to add `xcolor` along with `textcomp`

Comment: A current `listings` shouldn't let you use `upquote=true` if the `textcomp` package has not been loaded. So if your complete, small example above still gives the error you should (beside loading `textcomp`) also check your package version.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example works well if you add the two packages to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Tested with TeX Live 2012.

Comment: On my own examples, only `xcolor` is needed.